# How to test the performance of a getter function in a loop without the compiler optimizing the loop?

Tags: c++, optimization, profiling

I need to test the performance of a getter function (returns a `double`) in our codebase which has optimizations turned on (the compilation system is a bit complicated and I don't want to touch it unless I really have to).

I want to test it using a loop such as

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000; ++i) {
    auto scale = input.get_double();
  }
```

but I think this loop will get optimized away since it's doing the same thing every iteration. Is there a trick to make sure the loop doesn't get optimized away? I was considering doing

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000; ++i) {
    auto scale = input.get_double() + i;
  }
```

but I don't want the addition to be included in the runtime profiling.

Comment: is the `get_double()` just a `return variable;`?? or it does some calculations? If it's the first, why do you think it requires to be profiled? If it's the latter, I would consider changing the name first of all

Comment: you can try here: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: A side note: the reason the loop might be optimized away is not _"since it's doing the same thing every iteration"_, but rather because it might have no observable effect (if for example `input.get_double()` is just returning some data or doing a local calculation. See the "as-if" rule: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if.

Comment: Give `scale` something to do. For example, define and initialize outside of the loop. Sum the results of the calls inside the loop, and print the result after the loop.

Comment: @Federico It technically is just a return variable, but it goes through some hurdles before it gets to the return variable stage. It's a bit difficult to explain without having to introduce you to how the codebase is set up

Comment: @user4581301 I thought about doing that, but my concern there is the summation time may be on the same order as the `get_double()` time. Also if I simply do something like `scale += input.get_double()` within the loop, couldn't that get optimized away too? The compiler can see that that's just `scale = 2000 * input.get_double()`?

Comment: If that's the case you learn something: The getter is inconsequential.

Comment: imho the best would be to use a profiler to measure the getter in the real scenario. Even if you can manage to get the compiler to optimize what it should optimize and not optimize what it should not, you will only end up with something that is not the real scenario

Comment: @David do something with _`scale`_, e.g. write it to some logging framework, which doesn't impact time measures.

Comment: if you are worried about overhead introduced you can measure the overhead with some dummy getter that does nothing but return some value and measure with the actual getter, the difference gives you a rough idea of how long the getter takes to execute

Comment: As @wohlstad points out above, the key is observable. Print the result. Assigning is in a loop is ineffective, only the last assignment can have an observable effect and the compiler can discard everything else. Something else has to go wrong, perhaps there is a recognizable pattern it can exploit, in order for the compiler to realize the summation can be optimized.

Comment: That said, profile the program and see where the time is being lost. If the getter is not a dominant time-waster, anything you do to improve the getter will have minimal effect.

Comment: If you do a summation, then no the compiler cannot optimize the loop unless you use optimization flags specifying the floating-point operations are associative. `-Ofast`, `-ffast-math` or `-fassociative-math` do that for example (each one include the following). Your current code should be optimized out with optimization enabled. Please *check the assembly code*.